# Update sql table with php error

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I tried to update a MySQL database table (online) with a php function, but everytime that i click on "button update" it answers me:

> *Could not update data: Unknown column '$username' in 'where clause'*

can somebody help me with this error or only suggest me the correct way to resolve it?

here is it the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Update Name of my_table in MySQL Database</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['update']))
{
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'dbuser';
$dbpass = 'dbpassword';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$username = $_POST['username'];
$name = $_POST['name'];

$sql = 'UPDATE tbl_user SET name = $name WHERE username = $username';

mysql_select_db('my_table');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Updated data successfully\n";
mysql_close($conn);
}
else
{
?>
<form method="post" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">
<tr>
<td width="100">Usrename</td>
<td><input name="username" type="text" id="username"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100">Name</td>
<td><input name="name" type="text" id="name"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100"> </td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100"> </td>
<td>
<input name="update" type="submit" id="update" value="Update">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
<?php
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is it my_table columns:

```
id | username | password | email | name
```

Comment: desc your DB table 'tbl_usr", is it having a username column ??

Comment: id username password email name

Comment: If you're using the deprecated mysql_* API, please read up on at least [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chane this line of query You missing single quete around your variable.

```
$sql = 'UPDATE tbl_user SET name = $name WHERE username = $username';
```

to this

```
$sql = "UPDATE tbl_user SET name = '$name' WHERE username = '$username'";
```

Comment: thanks a lot.... i can t vote you for my reputation, but i want to say you thanks!!!!

Comment: of course, i need to wait other 5 minutes according rules to accept the answer!

Comment: @MarcC Just FYI (and for future readers that may copy'n'paste), using this answer's code and posting to the page with the username `'OR''='` will update the name of all users in the database.

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql="UPDATE tbl_user SET name = '".$name."' WHERE username = '".$username."'"
```

There is matter of quotes i think so this will work better because name and username fields contain string. concating  string is better solution when you work with string